# File validation not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i Am using cakephp. Condition is File input field in form is not mandatory and
Incase file is uploaded it must be either jpg or PDFs and file size must be less than 1 mb.
Issue is even if file is empty the error message "'Only pdf and jpg files'" is displayed.How to solve it.

```
            This is code of model:

              <?php
                  class Quote extends AppModel {
                      var $name = 'quotes';

                    public $validate = array(
    'b2c' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Enter the Requirement Type'
    ),//b2c

    'attachmenturl' => array(
        'extension' => array(
        'rule' => array('extension', array('pdf','jpg')),//rule
         'message' => 'Only pdf and jpg files',
         'last' => false
     ),//extension

        'filesize' => array(
         'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
         'message' => 'Image must be less than 1MB'
    )//filesize

        ),//attachmenturl

);//validate array
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As per:

> http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::extension

try:

```
public $validate = array(
    'attachmenturl' => array(
        'rule' => array(
            'extension',
            array('pdf', 'jpeg', 'jpg')
        ),
        'message' => 'Please supply a valid image.'
    )
);
```

Dont need to nest it in the extension array

Comment: what is the value of `$this->data[attachmenturl]` before you try to validate?

Comment: If there is no file the value is null.If there is a file to be uploaded it is an array with filename,tmp_name etc